# How to modify the last item of an array?

Tags: arrays, rust

Since `arr` is borrowed as mutable, the length of `arr` can't be gotten by calling `len()`. I'm stuck here, what's the right way to do it?

```
fn double_last(arr: &mut[i32]) -> &i32 {
    let last = &mut arr[arr.len() - 1];  // borrow checker error.
    //let last = &mut arr[3];            // fine
    *last *= 2;
    last
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = [1,2,3,4];
    println!("{}", double_last(&mut a));
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

Comment: The borrow checker has undergone a number of improvements since the question was asked, and the example can now be compiled without errors from version 2015 on. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2015&gist=a63ea9947bae9d2da196ad4de3cfeeec)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will hopefully be fixed with the introduction of non-lexical lifetimes and the accompanying changes soon into the future (seems like it could be solved?).

For now though, you can satisfy the borrow checker by splitting that calculation out:

```
let n = arr.len() - 1;
let last = &mut arr[n];
```

Answer (score 8):

If you only need the last, you can use `std::slice::last_mut`

```
fn double_last(arr: &mut[i32]) -> &i32 {
    let last = arr.last_mut().unwrap();
    *last *= 2;
    last
}
```

Comment: yes, much cleaner. and that reminds me the return type should be an Option in case of an empty array, thanks.

Comment: @limon , yes, if you cannot guarantee the array is not empty, or this this function is public, thus out side of your control on how they will be used, then `Option` is a better choice.